# AWS resource use optimization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am looking for any open source projects out there that will help optimize costs for AWS resources. The main thing I am looking for is the ability to turn off EC2 instances in a ASG and RDS instances during non-business hours and turn them back on during business hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloudwatch alarms to trigger an AWS Lambda function to turn on and off your instances at scheduled timings.

You can write your own logic in AWS lambda in any of your preferred languages supported by Lambda. One such example is in below article:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/

Answer (score 0):

You're going to run into problems terminating instances within an ASG since the ASG will just try to spin up a new instance to maintain health. You actually need a way to orchestrate the whole ASG itself. The way I might approach this is to tear down and spin up your pre-defined ASG using Lambda much like @alpesh mentioned. But I would orchestrate this using CloudWatch Events (which will make scheduled calls to Lambda). Store the ASG definition in S3 so you can edit it or version it when necessary (so that you don't have to edit your Lambda function itself). Just slurp it in from the Lambda function.

[What is Amazon CloudWatch Events?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html)

You can stop and start RDS instances using the same orchestration method. This is not an option if you run read replicas or Multi-AZ. If either of these are true you need to initiate a snapshot -> terminate RDS -> restore RDS from snapshot each time. Restoring might take a while depending on the size of your DB since RDS snapshots are more involved than performing a block-level snapshot/restore.

[Stopping an Amazon RDS DB Instance Temporarily](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_StopInstance.html)

Answer (score 0):

AWS already has a solution for this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/instance-scheduler/welcome.html